# Which code coverage tool will be helpful in Xcode for Swift projects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6, code-coverage

Which code coverage tool will be helpful in Xcode for Swift projects?  If not for Swift then what are the available tools for Objective-C code coverage?

Answer (score 6):

As of Xcode 7, code coverage is part of the testing capabilities:

> **Code coverage**: Visualize the completeness of your test suite by enabling code coverage for your scheme. The code coverage tab in the test report shows which files, functions and lines of code were exercised and, more importantly, which were not exercised. The source code editor can also show code coverage information inline, allowing you to see at a glance which lines—and parts of a line—the tests exercised.

[image]